# In War of the Worlds, is the Tripod that grabs Rachel really the same Tripod as in the beginning?

Tags: war-of-the-worlds

In the plot summary of *War of the Worlds* from wikipedia, it reads

> Ray cripples the probe using an axe, but Rachel is caught by a
>   Tripod, ironically the same one that Ray saw in the beginning that
>   destroyed the town.

Is there any evidence in the movie of this fact?

Answer (score 5):

It's exceptionally unlikely that it was.

When Rachel was grabbed, the family was several hundreds miles north of Jersey City where the original walkers broke through the Earth. It seems unlikely that the same walker would have traveled several hundred miles north and along the same route as Rachel and her family.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't.

There are lot of different tripods in the movie and they all look the same. There is no evidence at all and no hints in the movie that support this theory.